# Hibernate - вопрос по маппингу и подчеркиванию в IDE

Tags: java, hibernate

Использую Hibernate - 5.4.10.Final
IDE - IDEA Enterprise.

Конфиг хибера

```
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">*****</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в следующем подчеркивает красным, таблички и их поля в коде.

**Но все компилится и работает нормально!!**

Все поля и таблицы с аннотациями как и положено.
К базе коннект есть.
Классы добавлены в конфиг

```
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
            .addAnnotatedClass(DailyReport.class)
            .addAnnotatedClass(Car.class)
            .configure();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Если добавляю в hibernate.cfg.xml - маппинг вроде :

   ```
   <mapping class="model.DailyReport"/>
   <mapping class="model.Car"/>
   ```

подчеркивания исчезают.

Почему так происходит и как убрать эти гребанные подчеркивания ( без дублирования маппинга в XML конфиге ) якобы он ("Cant resolve symbol car")

2. Почему у меня не компилится и возникают ошибки при обращении к таблицам в базе, если я убираю аннотейтед класс ( new AnnotatedConfig - вообще у меня не видит ) и оставляю только маппинг в XML.

   ```
       Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
           .configure();
   ```

И да, когда я добавляю маппинг, он в персистансе отображает имена таблиц почему-то не правильно, не так как указано в аннотации к POJO классам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. курсор в место подчеркивания, alt + enter и выключите инспекцию

Comment: 2. Аннотация `Column` для БД

Comment: @dmtr что значит аннотация Column для БД? Что Вы эти хотели сказать?

Comment: Она задает имя столбца для таблиц в БД, а не для отображения в персистансе. @Васька

Comment: ок, я это знаю. Вопрос совершенно в другом был заключен.

Comment: В продолжение у предыдущему вопросу: зачем использовать ручное управление сессией, когда все это можно спрятать в репозитории и кастомизировать с помощью @Query-методов?

Answer (score 1):

*Данный ответ не является ответом к вопросу, а лишь помощь с опитимизацией кода.*

Если вы хотите вернуть типизированный список, то лучше это сделать с использованием `TypedQuery`:

```java
    //Get All Cars
    public List<Car> getAllCars(){

        List<Car> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            TypedQuery<Car> query = session.createQuery("from Car", Car.class);
            list = query.getResultList();

            session.clear();
            session.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо. А что за session.clesr и зачем он? И еще вопрос. Почему вы не закрыли сессию через session.close в finally? И по хорошему вроде надо отлавливать исключения при закрытии?

Comment: @Васька вопросы хорошие, но ответ дать не могу.

Answer (score 0):

Добавлять mapping в hibernate.cfg.xml надо, потому что ваша программа не может сама находить сущности, как это возможно при работе со Spring. Добавляя объекты в маппинг, вы говорите программе какие объекты участвуют при отправке данных в базу данных.